# make Folder in sdcard with password protected: android

Tags: android

i am saving video and image in a folder ..now i want to make this folder as password   protected , means while opening this folder needs to enter a password for view the file inside       it
     hope here ill get any relevant answer for doing this...if there some any other possible please suggest..

```
                     try {
                        dirName = "/mydirectory/";
                        fileName = new Long(
                                SystemClock.currentThreadTimeMillis())
                                .toString()
                                + ".png";
                    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                    try {
                        if (android.os.Environment
                                .getExternalStorageState()
                                .equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
                            File sdCard = Environment
                                    .getExternalStorageDirectory();
                            File dir = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                                    + dirName);
                            dir.mkdirs();

                            File file = new File(storedImagePath);

                            os = new FileOutputStream(file, true);

                            byte[] byteArray = receivedImageData.getBytes();

                            byteArray = Base64.decode(byteArray, 0);

                            os.write(byteArray);
                            os.flush();
                            os.close();

                        } else {

                        }

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                    }
```

Comment: Also, the only thing possible is Encrypt the files.

Comment: hi  user370305 , actually i have idea for encryption and decryption the sdcard contents but was trying to explore other thing except it..any way thanks for your responses...

Comment: You can make it un-readable but you can not provide security to it, If device is root or sdcard mounted on system then user can easily delete those files..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd like to suggest a different/feasible approach, **Encrypt your file**!

Look at [this answer!](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2743741/977676)

Even if you are successful in implementing a  password protection (Wow!) here are the cons,

1. This will only protect when your app is running.
2. SD cards are supposed to be transferred(Hence your app cannot protect the files on SDcard always).