# How to set a password for a folder programmatically in android

Tags: android, passwords, directory

Is there a way to set a password for a folder programmatically?

Comment: i think [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2743741/how-can-i-lock-files-in-android-using-java-code) may help u

Comment: refer this link http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal

Comment: @Ram kiran Yes it was helpful for nothing positive

Comment: there are some solutions like locking files using java. you can try it no..

Comment: @DixitPatel - Nope I am using the external storage in case. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

The best solution I can think of is to do it like you do in java: An example in [this link](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/locking-files-using-java/) describes as follows:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.FileLock;

public class FileLockTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        RandomAccessFile file = null;
        FileLock fileLock = null;
        try
        {
            file = new RandomAccessFile("FileToBeLocked", "rw");
            FileChannel fileChannel = file.getChannel();

            fileLock = fileChannel.tryLock();
            if (fileLock != null){
                System.out.println("File is locked");
                accessTheLockedFile();
            }
        }finally{
            if (fileLock != null){
                fileLock.release();
            }
        }
    }

    static void accessTheLockedFile(){

        try{
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("FileToBeLocked");
            int data = input.read();
            System.out.println(data);
        }catch (Exception exception){
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How to apply this for a folder with hundreds maybe thousands of files?

Comment: @Sathirar : put them all in a folder and lock that folder maybe