# how to securely store a image and video in android so other application can not use?

Tags: android, video, android-image

I have lots of images and video, so I cannot store in internal storage. 
I want to store it in external storage and I don't want to show this images and video to user. It can not be copy when it connected to USB.
I already tried to encrypt a video and images, but it takes to much time to decrypt a video and it is not played directly. This solution is told by so many people on stack overflow but it is not feasible for me.
I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494271/how-to-set-a-password-for-a-folder-programmatically-in-android) solution,
so please give me the another solution if it is possible.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: AFAIK this feature is included in Android 4.4+. But not sure what are your requisites

Comment: I want to store images and video in sdcard but it can not access by other user if they connect the phone with PC via USB. It can not be able to access outside the application anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory (note the dot prefix in the filename). This will prevent Android's media scanner from reading your media files and including them in apps like Gallery or Music. for example , you store your images and video in sdcard/yourappname/
then put .nomedia file in sdcard/yourappname/.nomedia
And then other application can not read your media files

Comment: I tried this. But it is not feasible because images is not shown in application too.

Comment: Asha, please provide your code snippet so that i can check